# Preventing temporary table usage in query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm running explain extended on the below query and I'm not sure why this is happening.  I've added an index on `site.id, site.parent_id, and site.enabled` but I'm still seeing that it's creating a temporary table.

```
SELECT site.label AS site_label, deal . * , site.id AS site_id
FROM site
LEFT JOIN deal ON ( deal.site_id = site.id
AND DAYOFYEAR( deal.created ) = DAYOFYEAR( NOW( ) ) ) 
WHERE (
site.id =2
OR site.parent_id =2
)
AND site.enabled =1
ORDER BY site.order ASC , deal.created DESC
```

Any suggestions on how I can prevent this from using a temporary table?

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  site    ALL id,parent_id,id_2   NULL    NULL    NULL    10  100.00  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  deal    ref site_id site_id 4   dealclippings.site.id   235 100.00
```

Comment: Is your aim to get the query being executed faster or just to avoid `temporary table` label? `I'm still seeing that it's creating a temporary table` so what?

Answer (score 2):

You perform a query that cannot be optimized well:

1. Try to avoid using of `OR`
2. Mysql cannot optimize (use indexes) for sorting in different directions (you use both `ASC` and `DESC` in one `ORDER BY`)
3. `DAYOFYEAR( deal.created )` avoid using functions over fields you search by

But you shouldn't aware of that `temporary table` label until you are satisfied with query performance, or aren't you?

Comment: Thanks for the deails.... I am satisfied, but since it's the primary query on my site, I thought I'd take a look anyways to see if it could be improved.

Comment: @Webnet: 10x235 rows is too small amount to worry about. But anyway keep in mind items 1,2,3 I've mentioned above